# Find a region with maximum sum of top-K points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

My problem is: we have N points in a 2D space, each point has a positive weight. Given a query consisting of two real numbers a,b and one integer k, find the position of a rectangle of size a x b, with edges are parallel to axes, so that the sum of weights of top-k points, i.e. k points with highest weights, covered by the rectangle is maximized?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

P.S.:
There are two related problems, which are already well-studied:

- Maximum region sum: find the rectangle with the highest total weight sum. Complexity: NlogN.
- top-K query for orthogonal ranges: find top-k points in a given rectangle. Complexity: O(log(N)^2+k).

Comment: What if I choose the rectangle covering all points? Weights will be maximized

Comment: @Nyavro: The size of rectangle is given, i.e. a x b. So you cannot choose the rectangle covering all points.

Comment: Rectangles with any rotation? Or rectangles parallel to a given pair of axes?

Comment: @TomZych Rectangle's edges are parallel to axes.

Comment: This might not be helpful, but with the given restrictions, I think it's safe to say that if we take any rectangle (even the optimal one), we could move it (without losing any of our points inside) so that one of each vertical and horizontal sides lie on 1 or more points. Maybe this could be used in some way, like a sweep algorithm

Comment: @PiotrPytlik Sweeping rectangle is the exhaustive way to find optimal rectangle, and it is very inefficient. In maximum region sum problem, the solution is sweeping a horizontal line, instead of rectangle, and it is more efficient. You can find the algorithm in the paper "[A unified algorithm for finding maximum and minimum object enclosing rectangles and cuboids](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219500029X)".

Comment: Do you need an absolute maximum? Or will a competitive maximum suffice? My first thought was this might be one of those kinds of problems that gets stuck at local maxima.

Comment: @eh9 I don't get it. I need that the output is maximized.

Comment: "Competitive" seems to have acquired a different flavor of meaning since I learned it. I mean a near-optimum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm

Comment: @eh9 I understand. I need exact solution. However, if you have an idea for approximation one, can you share?

Comment: Now that I've considered the problem more thoroughly, the brute force algorithm runs in O(N((log N)^2+k)). For each point, consider the rectangle whose lower left vertex is the point. Find the top k points for that rectangle. Record the maximum value. This performance is well within polynomial time, so an approximation probably won't be necessary.

Comment: @eh9 : Thanks for the answer. However, I'm afraid that your answer is not complete. For example, if k = 2 and a = b = 2, we have 2 points A(1,2) and B(2,1), then the answer is the region covering both A and B; but your algorithm fails to find this.

Comment: Well, OK. I was only concerned with asymptotic performance. Check each of the four rectangles for each point. Doesn't change the big-O estimate.

Comment: @eh9: Your solution is still not complete. Overall, you need to check every possible axb-rectangle totally covered by, i.e. lies inside, (2a)x(2b)-rectangle centered by each point; not just 4 rectangles as you did.

Comment: Four rectangles are indeed insufficient. Every possible rectangle, however, is too many. The optimal rectangles are not unique. Given an optimal rectangle, we can shift it right until it intersects the leftmost point that it contains. This will have the same optimum value (although it might contain more points). Similarly, you can shift it up until it intersects the lowermost point. Thus, rather than examining points and four rectangles, we brute-force by examining point pairs, defining a canonical rectangle with one point on the leftmost vertical and the other on the lowermost horizontal.

Comment: Even with that, it's still a polynomial time algorithm, so no approximation is necessary. O(N^2((log N)^2+k)) at most.

Comment: @eh9: Can you check your algorithm with higher k, such as k = 3,4,5...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce this problem into finding two points in the rectangle: rightmost and topmost. So effectively you can select every pair of points and calculate the top-k weight (which according to you is O(log(N)^2+k)). Complexity: O(N^2*(log(N)^2+k)).

Now, given two points, they might not form a valid pair: they might be too far or one point may be right and top of the other point. So, in reality, this will be much faster.

My guess is the optimal solution will be a variation of maximum region sum problem. Could you point to a link describing that algorithm?

Comment: Your idea is very interesting. I will consider it. For the maximum region sum problem, we can study it in the paper whose title is "A unified algorithm for finding maximum and minimum object enclosing rectangles and cuboids".

Answer (score 0):

An non-optimal answer is the following:

1. Generate all the possible k-plets of points (they are N × N-1 × … × N-k+1, so this is O(N<sup>k</sup>) and can be done via recursion).
2. Filter this list down by eliminating all k-plets which are not enclosed in a a×b rectangle: this is a O(k N<sup>k</sup>) at worst.
3. Find the k-plet which has the maximum weight: this is a O(k N<sup>k-1</sup>) at worst.

Thus, this algorithm is O(k N<sup>k</sup>).

**Improving the algorithm**

Step 2 can be integrated in step 1 by stopping the branch recursion when a set of points is already too large. This does not change the need to scan the element at least once, but it can reduce the number significantly: think of cases where there are no solutions because all points are separated more than the size of the rectangle, that can be found in O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Also, the permutation generator in step 1 can be made to return the points in order by x or y coordinate, by pre-sorting the point array correspondingly. This is useful because it lets us discard a bunch of more possibilities up front. Suppose the array is sorted by y coordinate, so the k-plets returned will be ordered by y coordinate. Now, supposing we are discarding a branch because it contains a point whose y coordinate is outside the max rectangle, we can also discard all the next sibling branches because their y coordinate will be more than of equal to the current one which is already out of bounds.

This adds O(n log n) for the sort, but the improvement can be quite significant in many cases -- again, when there are many outliers. The coordinate should be chosen corresponding to the minimum rectangle side, divided by the corresponding side of the 2D field -- by which I mean the maximum coordinate minus the minimum coordinate of all points.

Finally, if all the points lie within an a×b rectangle, then the algorithm performs as O(k N<sup>k</sup>) anyways. If this is a concrete possibility, it should be checked, an easy O(N) loop, and if so then it's enough to return the points with the top N weights, which is also O(N).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Because in my data, N is huge (~1M points), I think your solution is not efficient. Btw, if a region contains less than k points, its score is the sum of weights of all points. So there is always an answer.

Comment: @user2210078 I think we can improve if you have more details about your case. How much is k? How are the points distributed (e.g. How evenly, but also in how much space? What is the range of a and b? These are all things we can maybe use to make the algorithm more efficient

Comment: I aim to design an efficient algorithm for any data, like the solution for Maximum region sum I mentioned in my post. k may be small, about 2,3,5 or 10. Of course, if we know some characteristics of data, such as point distribution, we can exploit them to improve our algorithm. In this case, one example you can consider that our dataset is set of places (restaurants, cinemas, ...) from a city, a state or whole US, and weights are their scores from Yelp or Foursquare.